# ¿Cómo podría mapear un json con datos extraídos de un excel?

Tags: python, json, excel, diccionarios

llevo bastante intentando mapear un diccionario con datos de un excel...
Resulta que yo tengo este archivo, el cual debo leer las columnas de la E en adelante, eso ya lo tengo resuelto, la columna B son datos de una base de datos que tengo mapeado en un diccionario llamado standard, donde lo que se ve en las celdas son las llaves y el valor su ID, eso también lo tengo resuelto...
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Mi problema es que no he podido realizar este diccionario:

```
{
    "name": "example 1",
    "key": [
        {
            "celda_B_id": 1,# es 1 porque en el diccionario "standard" A es 1
            "celda_F": 1 
        },
        {
            "celda_B_id": 2,#es 2 porque en el diccionario "standard" A01 es 2
            "celda_F": 2
        },
        {
            "celda_B_id": 3,#es 3 porque en el diccionario "standard" A01.1 es 3
            "celda_F": 90
        }
    ]
}
```

la llave "name" deben ser los nombres de la fila 1 de las columnas de la E hasta la ultima que exista, la llave "celda_B_id" la debo obtener de un diccionario con datos de la base de datos y la llave celda_F deben ser los datos de cada celda de las columnas de la E en adelante.

Este es el diccionario mapeado de la base de datos, el cual debo unir con el primero.

```
standard = {
    "A": 1,
    "A01": 2,
    "A01.1": 3,
    "A01.11": 4,
    "A01.12": 5,
    "A01.13": 6,
    "A01.14": 7,
    "A01.15": 8,
    "A01.16": 9,
    "A01.19": 10
}
```

para obtener la información de las celdas estoy usando un ciclo for y openpyxl y lo que llevo hasta ahora es esto... :I

```
nms = []
sect = {}
dct = {'name': '', 'sectors': []}
for row in range(1, sheet.max_row + 1):
    sector_id = None
    for column in range(2, sheet.max_column + 1):
        cell = sheet.cell(row=row, column=column).value
        if column > 4 and row == 1:
            map_name_source[column] = cell
            dct['name'] = cell
            nms.append(dct)
        else:
            if column == 2 and column > 1:
                dct["sectors"].append({'sector_id': 
                standard.get(cell)})
```

Comment: ¿Y cual es el problema? No queda claro

Comment: le problema es que no he podido mapear el diccionario:
{
    "name": "example 1",
    "key": [
        {
            "celda_B_id": 1,
            "celda_F": 1
        },
        {
            "celda_B_id": 2,
            "celda_F": 2
        },
        {
            "celda_B_id": 90,
            "celda_F": 3
        }
    ]
}

Comment: Edité la pregunta, a ver si se entiende mejor...